gsap: motion path keeps moving back issue
please see this codepen demo
I am learning gsap MotionPathPlugin, I have a simple SVG cubic curve:
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" class="group-elements" data-motion-path="M 0 0 C 432 0 576 291 884 291">
    <path d="M 0 0 C 432 0 576 291 884 291 v 1.5 C 576 292.5 432 1.5 0 1.5" fill="url(#start-lgradient-base-lines)"></path>
    <clipPath id="start-clip-path-0">
        <path d="M 0 0 C 432 0 576 291 884 291 v 1.5 C 576 292.5 432 1.5 0 1.5"></path>
    </clipPath>
    <rect id="start-rect-0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#start-lgradient-02)" clip-path="url(#start-clip-path-0)" x="-100%"></rect>
    <g class="dot" style="opacity: 0;">
        <circle r="30" fill="url(#start-rgradient-dot-back)"></circle>
        <circle r="15" fill="url(#start-rgradient-dot-front)"></circle>
        <circle r="2.25" fill="white"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>

and I try to move the particle along the path.
const groups = document.querySelectorAll(".group-elements");

gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

const timeline = gsap.timeline();
groups.forEach((group, index) => {
  const particle = group.querySelector("g.dot");
  const path = group.querySelector("path");
  const clipPath = group.querySelector("clipPath");
  const rect = group.querySelector("rect");
  gsap.set(particle, { opacity: 1 });
  timeline.to(
    particle,
    {
      duration: 5,
      ease: "power2.inOut",
      motionPath: {
        path: path,
        align: path,
        alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
        autoRotate: 90,
      }
    },
    index, 
  );
});

but what I got is: the particle move along the path, but then moves back to where it started
I only want a one way movement, I will be more than glad if u can give me a hand.

You motion path is a closed shape, that's why the element moves back. You can reduce it to M 0 0 C 432 0 576 291 884 291 and it should work

Maybe on the motionPath object you need end: 1. From the docs it says "The position along the path at which to end, where 0 is the beginning, 1 is the end," https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/MotionPathPlugin

Please make sure your code examples render a visible result. Besides, please prefer to embed examples as code snippets to prevent expired external links. Here is a running example illustrating the aforementioned motion path modification: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/eYazzVN?editors=1010
